# store a data in list from a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

is it possible to use a loop to store a data in a list from a dictionary??
like this::

```
for z in range(0,8):            # converting the final list to right number from the dictionary
    print (z)
    if temp[z]==1: 
        convert[z]==a['X_%d=1'%(z+1)]
    elif temp[z]==2:
        convert[z]==a['X_%d=2'%(z+1)]
```

every time i run the code it gives me this message:
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: What is `temp`? what is `convert`? What is `a`? Provide the complete code alongside a complete explanation of what you are trying to do and maybe add some examples for better understanding.

Comment: please define your use-case or what you want to do, define input/output of your desired algorithm and what you have tried to do so far (what is temp/convert used for)